# Remove commits from history

Tags: git, github

How can I remove the last 3 commits that I made to my repository from the history? And with history, I mean both the local history, and the public history from GitHub.

Comment: @NoNameProvided that guy didn't push the changes, I did.

Comment: You need to force push `git push --force` to overwrite your remote branch.

Comment: Is the repo / the branch shared? If not, go for @NoNameProvided's solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+last+commits